# How do I change the color of this area of my Windows 7 windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, colors, gui, user-interface

I see this color *everywhere* in my Windows applications. I can't find anywhere that I set a color that is this disjointed with the rest of the color scheme (which is gray, not blue).

How do I change it to match everything else?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about menu bars or tool bars (which I would assume from your screenshot but I'm not too sure), then this is all controlled by the theme you selected. If you don't like it, then you'll have to use the Windows classic theme.

Comment: Really, so Windows 7 lets you muck with everything but this one color? Are there 3rd party themes that I can use?

Comment: That seems to always involve things like hacking a system DLL and such. Never really tried it.

Comment: To reiterate CrossHatch's question, are there any customized 3rd party themes available that change this color?

Comment: To reiterate my answer, that seems to always involve things like hacking a system DLL and such. Never really tried it.

Comment: I used to use http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/ to skin WinXP back in the day. Looks like they've kept up with support through Windows 10 even. Problem is, this solution requires complete reskinning; you download individual themes and, while they may have some minor customization or variations to choose from, the entire skin is applied to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely dependent on the application in question. Without knowing which applications you are referring to it is impossible to be specific.

And, of course, some applications provide no ability to change colours, or very limited ability.